# How to Update unique data values for duplicated project number by joining duplicated project number from other two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to update unique values for duplicated project number in a table by joining two different table,for joining the common column is project_number, but it has duplicated values of project number, while i tried using mysql query but i got duplicating of datas for duplicated project number

```
UPDATE  table_A T1 JOIN                              //join table T1 andT2
(
SELECT 
    S.PROJECT_NUM,
    S.STATION_ID AS STATION_ID,
    S.STATION_FROM
FROM
    table_S S
        INNER JOIN                                   //(join table s and p)=T2
    table_P P ON (S.PROJECT_NUM = P.J_PROJ_NU    
        AND S.STATION_FROM = P.STATION
        )T2

        ON T1.PROJECT_NUMBER=T2.PROJECT_NUM
        SET T1.FK_STATION_ID=T2.STATION_ID;
```

Table table_s

```
PROJECT_NUM | STATION_ID     | STATION_FROM 
AABB        |        1a      |     101
AABB        |        1b      |     201
AABB        |        1c      |     301
AABB        |        1d      |     401
bbaa        |        2a2     |     501
bbaa        |        2b2     |     601
```

Table table_P

```
J_PROJ_NU  | STATION   | PRMRY_KEY
AABB       |     101   |    1001
AABB       |     201   |    2002 
AABB       |     301   |    3003
AABB       |     401   |    4004
bbaa       |     501   |    5005
bbaa       |     601   |    6006
```

The common columns for **table_s** and **table_p** are project number(J_PROJ_NU == PROJECT_NUM ) and station(STATION == STATION_FROM )

The result what i have got

```
proj_num  |    station_id  |  prmry_key
AABB      |        1a      |     1
AABB      |        1a      |     2
AABB      |        1a      |     3
AABB      |        1a      |     4
bbaa      |        2a2     |     5
bbaa      |        2a2     |     6
```

The result what i need

```
proj_num  |    station_id  |  prmry_key
AABB      |        1a      |     1
AABB      |        1b      |     2
AABB      |        1c      |     3
AABB      |        1d      |     4
bbaa      |        2a2     |     5
bbaa      |        2b2     |     6
```

Comment: You would need to share sample data from both tables `table_S ` and `table_P`.

Comment: as you mentioned I updated the question @GMB